# resolving error message Error: The schema does not contain the path: spinach. (failed at: undefined which is a type: "object")

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-router-dom, yup, react-functional-component

1. this is a pizza form.
2. When I click on a radio to select a sauce the page crashes.
3. the desire is for the user to name the order.
4. then only be able to select 1 type of sauce.
5. then select toppings
6. then submit.
7. should only be able to submit after name field and selections are selected.
8. then to validate the form?

   import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

   import * as yup from "yup";

   const formSchema = yup.object().shape({

   id: yup.string().required("Required"),

   name: yup

   ```
   .string()

   .min(2, "You name should have 2 characters")

   .required("You don't have a name?"),
   ```

   type: yup

   ```
   .string()

   .min(3, "Must be at least 3 characters")

   .required("Required"),
   ```

   value: yup.string().required("Required"),

   });

   const PizzaForm = () => {

   // managing state for form

   const [formState, setFormState] = useState({

   ```
   id: "",

   name: "",

   type: "",

   value: "",

   addOns: "",
   ```

   });

   const [errors, setErrors] = useState({

   ```
   id: "",

   name: "",

   type: "",

   value: "",

   addOns: "",
   ```

   });

   const [buttonDisabled, setButtonDisabled] = useState(true);

   const validate = (e) => {

   const value =

   e.target.type === "checkbox" ? e.target.checked : e.target.name;

   ```
   yup

     .reach(formSchema, e.target.name)

     .validate(e.target.value)

     .then((valid) => {

       setErrors({

         ...errors,

         [e.target.name]: "",

       });

     })

     .catch((err) => {

       setErrors({

         ...errors,

         [e.target.name]: err.errors[0],

       });

     });
   ```

   };

   // formSubmit function

   const formSubmit = (e) => {

   ```
   e.preventDefault();

   console.log("form submitted!", formState);
   ```

   };

   // onChange function

   const onChange = (e) => {

   ```
   e.persist();

   validate(e); /*something wrong here, crashes when a radio is selected*/

   console.log(e.target.value, e.target.checked);

   const value = e.target.type === "radio" ? e.target.checked : 

   e.target.value;

   setFormState({ ...formState, [e.target.name]: value });
   ```

   };

   // handleChange function

   const handleChange = (e) => {

   ```
   e.persist();

   setFormState({

     ...formState,

     addOns: [formState.addOns, e.target.value],

   });
   ```

   };

   // use effect function

   useEffect(() => {

   ```
   formSchema.isValid(formState).then((valid) => {

     setButtonDisabled(!valid);

   });
   ```

   }, [formState]);

   return (

   ```
   <div>

     <form onSubmit={formSubmit}>

       <label htmlFor="name">

         Name Your Pizza:

         <input

           type="text"

           name="name"

           id="name"

           placeholder="Save for future orders!"

           value={formState.name}

           onChange={onChange}

         />

         {errors.name.length > 0 ? (

           <p className="error">{errors.name}</p>

         ) : null}

       </label>

       <h1> Build Your Own Pizza! </h1>

       <label htmlFor="size">

         <h3> What Size Pizza? </h3>

         Pizza Size:

         <select id="psize" name="psize">

           <option value="Small">Small</option>

           <option value="Medium">Medium</option>

           <option value="Large">Large</option>

           <option value="Extralarge">Extra Large</option>

         </select>

       </label>

       <h3> Select Your Sauce: </h3>

       <label htmlFor="redsauce" className="redsauce">

         <input

           type="radio"

           name="redsauce"

           value={formState.name}

           onChange={onChange}

         />

         Original Red

       </label>

       <label htmlFor="garlic" className="garlic">

         <input

           type="radio"

           name="garlic"

           value={formState.name}

           onChange={onChange}

         />

         Garlic Ranch

       </label>


       <label htmlFor="bbq" className="bbq">

         <input

           type="radio"

           name="bbq"

           value={formState.name}

           onChange={onChange}

         />

         BBQ Sauce

       </label>

       <label htmlFor="spinach" className="spinach">

         <input

           type="radio"

           name="spinach"

           value={formState.name}

           onChange={onChange}

         />

         Spinach Alfredo

       </label>

       <h3> Select Your Toppings: </h3>

       <label htmlFor="toppings">

         Toppings: Plain

         <input

           id="toppings1"

           type="checkbox"

           name="addOns"

           value={formState.name}

           onChange={handleChange}

         />

         <h3> Select Your Cheese: </h3>

         Chedder

         <input

           id="toppings2"

           type="checkbox"

           name="addOns"

           onChange={handleChange}

         />

         Cheese

         <input

           id="toppings3"

           type="checkbox"

           name="addOns"

           onChange={handleChange}

         />

         Three Cheese

         <input

           id="toppings4"

           type="checkbox"

           name="addOns"

           onChange={handleChange}

         />

         ExtraCheese

         <input

           id="toppings5"

           type="checkbox"

           name="addOns"

           onChange={handleChange}

         />

         <h3> Select Your Meat: </h3>

         Pepporoni

         <input

           id="toppings6"

           type="checkbox"

           name="addOns"

           onChange={handleChange}

         />

         Sausage

         <input

           id="toppings7"

           type="checkbox"

           name="addOns"

           onChange={handleChange}

         />

         Canadian Bacon

         <input

           id="toppings8"

           type="checkbox"

           name="addOns"

           onChange={handleChange}

         />

         Spicy Italian Sausage

         <input

           id="toppings9"

           type="checkbox"

           name="addOns"

           onChange={handleChange}

         />

         GrilledChicken

         <input

           id="toppings10"

           type="checkbox"

           name="addOns"

           onChange={handleChange}

         />

         <h3> Select Other Toppings: </h3>

         Onions

         <input

           id="toppings11"

           type="checkbox"

           name="addOns"

           onChange={handleChange}

         />

         Green Peppers

         <input

           id="toppings12"

           type="checkbox"

           name="addOns"

           onChange={handleChange}

         />

         Diced Tomatoes

         <input

           id="toppings13"

           type="checkbox"

           name="addOns"

           onChange={handleChange}

         />

         Black Olives

         <input

           id="toppings14"

           type="checkbox"

           name="addOns"

           onChange={handleChange}

         />

         Roasted Garlic

         <input

           id="toppings15"

           type="checkbox"

           name="addOns"

           onChange={handleChange}

         />

         Artichoke Hearts

         <input

           id="toppings16"

           type="checkbox"

           name="addOns"

           onChange={handleChange}

         />

         Pineapple

         <input

           id="toppings17"

           type="checkbox"

           name="addOns"

           onChange={handleChange}

         />

       </label>

       <h3>Any Special Instructions?</h3>

       <label htmlFor="instructions">

         Special Instructions:

         <textarea name="instructions" />

       </label>

       <button disabled={buttonDisabled}>Submit</button>

     </form>

   </div>
   ```

   );
   };

   export default PizzaForm;

Comment: I think you should edit your question. Code is hard to read actually

Answer (score 1):

```
const formSchema = yup.object().shape({
  id: yup.string().required("Required"),
  name: yup.string().min(2, "You name should have 2 characters")
        .required("You don't have a name?"),
  type: yup.string().min(3, "Must be at least 3 characters").required("Required"),
  value: yup.string().required("Required"),
});
```

Your schema looks like this.
I have fixed this error in my code by adding the property yup is complaining about and by defining its type as per type the error is throwing.
***In your case it is 'spinach' of type object***

so add the following line to your yup schema:

```
spinach: yup.object()
```

set it as required if you consider it required

```
spinach: yup.object().required("Required"),
```

Your form contains this field and the yup schema does not.

Usually i did not notice that it was required to have all property names listed in the schema. The time i had this error is when i was switching between 2 schemas to submit a full object or a draft version. The draft version didn't have some properties listed yup complained about.